# How can i deploy contract with > 4.7 Mgas required on Ropsten?

Tags: gas, ropsten, gas-limit

I was able to deploy contract that requires more gas than default **Ropsten** block gas limit:
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x7c40cd2c539c03d110da8988641518ff6ff907a284f5074ed3d8517eb80b51f9 (**5594037** > 4.7M)

For some reason i can't do the same again with:

> $geth --verbosity "4" -rpc --nousb --ipcdisable --rpcaddr "127.0.0.1" --rpccorsdomain "" --rpcvhosts "" --syncmode "fast" --rpcapi="db,personal,eth,net,web3,admin" --cache=2048 --testnet --mine --targetgaslimit 7000000

Does `--targetgaslimit` work for Ropsten (not private network)? How can i deploy it **without splitting/using libraries/etc**?

Currently i'm getting Remix deploy error (connected to `Web3 provider`):

> creation of Contract errored: exceeds block gas limit

PS. I did it few times so i'm absolutely sure it's doable. But i can't understand what affects this and how can i deploy it intentionally.

Comment: why aren't you using private chain for tests?

Comment: first i test with private network and custom genesis file. then i test with ropsten as it's close to main net.

Comment: well, I guess you will have to pay for the transaction on the Main Net , then.

Comment: i'm talking about ropsten network, it's free

Comment: you can't deploy a contract that uses more Gas than the block limit allows

Comment: i did it few times, see https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x7c40cd2c539c03d110da8988641518ff6ff907a284f5074ed3d8517eb80b51f9, https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x6889604e2ff7c02d4a8eb9ec9878642c3bad478e3cb1eb90180224daded6d7f6

Comment: but the gas there is 6M, your contract uses 5M, so you can deploy it

Comment: how can you explain i can deploy the contract if it requires more gas than block gas limit? i do set gas limit more than 6M while deploying but the transaction is not accepted because of block gas limit

Comment: because the gas limit for block on Ropsten is 6M

Comment: no, it's 4.7M https://ropsten.etherscan.io/block/3883239. otherwise i don't have any problems with deployment at all. was it changed?

Comment: you probably was able to do it 2 weeks ago because there was more demand for mining, but since block gas limit is dynamically adjusted , right now due to low demand, you won't be able to do it. You can setup a rig become a miner and vote to increase block limit until it reaches your block limit target, or just pay for the transaction on the Main Net.

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/31491/how-is-the-block-gas-limit-dynamically-adjusted

Comment: i see, thanks for explanation. i can see block gas limit in that blocks (where i was able to deploy) was really 6M

Comment: any chance to evaluate the trend? ("when will it be high demand for mining and it will be set back to 6M"?)